# ¿Como se dice "Free time" en Español?

Tags: traducción

¿Como se dice "Free time" en español?
Los traductores no tienen una bien traducción.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece bien "tiempo libre":

> El tiempo libre se define como un tiempo fuera de las obligaciones personales, o lo que es lo mismo, el tiempo que queda tras haber satisfecho todas las necesidades y obligaciones.

Fuente: [Divulgación Dinámica](https://www.divulgaciondinamica.es/concepto-de-ocio-y-tiempo-libre/)

Comment: Mucho Gracias!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Free time = tiempo libre

> She spent her free time shopping
> Ella empleó su **tiempo libre** haciendo compras.

> I had little money and little free time
> Tengo poco dinero y poco **tiempo libre**

> Do you have some free time?
> Tienes algún **tiempo libre**?